# document.elementFromPoint returning null on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I am using the document.elementFromPoint for getting the selected element for dragging it. But it returns null. When i debug the same and then re run the same code, object is returned.

Following is the code:

```
function GetZoneFromPoint(x, y, prtDrag, elemIBeam,evnt) {
    if (x == null || y == null || prtDrag == null || elemIBeam == null)
        alert("Null in GetZone");
    var prtDragZIndexOld = prtDrag.style.zIndex;
    var elemIBeamZIndexOld = elemIBeam.style.zIndex;
    prtDrag.style.zIndex = -1;
    elemIBeam.style.zIndex = -1;
    var zone;
    zone = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    prtDrag.style.zIndex = prtDragZIndexOld;
    elemIBeam.style.zIndex = elemIBeamZIndexOld;
    if (zone == null) {
        zone = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
        if (zone == null) {
            debugger;
            zone = event.rangeParent;
        }
    }
    if (zone == null) {
        alert('null');
        return null;
    }
    if (x < 0 || x > document.body.clientWidth ||
      y < 0 || y > document.body.clientHeight) {
        zone = null;
    }
    else if ((zone.className == 'LayoutWellElement') ||
           (zone.className == 'LayoutMainElement') ||
           (zone.className == 'ElementFrame')) {
        while ((!FIsZone(zone)) && (zone.tagName != 'BODY')) {
            zone = zone.parentElement;
        }
    }
    if (!FIsZone(zone)) {
        zone = null;
    }
    return zone;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's look like we have the same nasty idea, haha. But i'm working on object collision. Look, where you call GetZoneFromPoint. Cursor click event only invoked in browser, right? So, no need to check x or y, just zone=null at first. You double check elementFromPoint for what while x & y unchanged? I'm done work flow here.

some tips:
- I have 2 'absolute' DIV objects called A & B which B is overlap A at bottom right corner.
- Use like this:
    var X=parseInt(B.offsetLeft);
    var Y=parseInt(B.offsetTop);
    alert(document.elementFromPoint(X,Y).innerHTML);
- Why parse? offsetLeft return in format: number+"px"
- The result is: IE->return A while FF->B
- If X-1 or Y-1, both browsers return A.
- Final words: don't use document.body.clientWidth alone check resolution, try this document.body.clientWidth-o.clientWidth. Hope these give you a power up bonus. Cheer!